# Laravel - How to resolve the error Method paginate does not exist

Tags: laravel

I want to paginate my join query. It displays: Method paginate does not exist.

I have written the query in controller

```
    public function userBilling()
    {
    $billings = DB::table("billings")
        ->select("billings.email", "billings.plan","users.name","users.username", DB::raw("SUM(played_game.amount) as total"))
        ->join("users","users.email","=","billings.email")
        ->groupBy("users.email","users.name","users.username","billings.plan")
        ->orderByRaw('billings.email DESC')
        ->get()
       ->paginate(15);
         return view('report.userBilling', compact('billings'));        
    }
```

Error:

> Method paginate does not exist.
>   How do I resolve the error and do my pagination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to call `paginate` on a collection, `paginate` is a method on the Query builder so try this instead:

```
public function userBilling()
{
    $billings = DB::table("billings")
        ->select("billings.email", "billings.plan","users.name","users.username", DB::raw("SUM(played_game.amount) as total"))
        ->join("users","users.email","=","billings.email")
        ->groupBy("users.email","users.name","users.username","billings.plan")
        ->orderByRaw('billings.email DESC')
        ->paginate(15);

    return view('report.userBilling', compact('billings'));        
}
```

notice the `get()` method is removed.

Comment: When I removed the get, it works but not showing the page count. It displays only the first page of 15 items

Comment: And you are sure that you have more than 15 records based on your query? Do you have `{{ $billings->links() }}` in your view?

Comment: I have more than 15 records.  Which one is {{ $billings->links() }}

Comment: You need to add that in your blade view in order to show pagination links. `Next`, `Previous` buttons and the number of pages with the results

Comment: More on this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination#displaying-pagination-results).